# Why am I getting this ClassCastException during an assignment where the two types are the same? (Groovy / Hibernate)

Tags: hibernate, grails, groovy, classcastexception

I have the following classes defined:

```
enum FruitTypeEnum {
    APPLE,
    BANANA,
    NONE
}

// POGO
class FruitDTO {
    FruitTypeEnum fruitType
}

// Hibernate Entity
abstract class Farm {
    FruitTypeEnum fruitType
}

private getFruitDTO(Farm farm) {
    def fruitDTO = new FruitDTO()
    fruitDTO.fruitType = farm.fruitType
    fruitDTO
}
```

When I attempt to execute the `getFruitDTO` function, 50% of the time the assignment `fruitDTO.fruitType = farm.fruitType` throws the following exception:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: java.lang.ClassCastException@564a5444
 at FarmController.getFruitDTO(FarmController.groovy:126)
```

I have attached the debugger and verified that the left hand side and the right hand side of the assignment are both the same datatype. So how am I getting a `ClassCastException`?

Answer (score 1):

Because the `farm` parameter is a Hibernate entity, it may be a `HibernateProxy` instance. You would think that one would get an explicit exception stating that when you attempt to access the `type` field, but for some reason in this case you get the `ClassCastException` I posted above. If you run the debugger and take a look at the code you will see that both sides of the assignment are indeed the exact same class, but the `farm` instance will be of type `Farm$HibernateProxy$...` if indeed it is a proxy object.

Just [unwrap the proxy](https://gorm.grails.org/6.0.x/api/org/grails/orm/hibernate/proxy/HibernateProxyHandler.html#unwrapIfProxy(java.lang.Object)) and you will avoid this error :-)

Comment: "If you run the debugger and take a look at the code you will see that both sides of the assignment are indeed the exact same class, but the farm instance will be of type Farm$HibernateProxy$... if indeed it is a proxy object" - Are you saying that both sides are indeed a proxy object?  I would not expect those 2 objects to be the exact same class.  I would expect only the RHS to be the proxy.

Comment: Hi @JeffScottBrown, in my comment "both sides of the assignment are indeed the exact same class" I was just noting that, according to the IDE, both sides are portrayed as being the same class (`Farm`). However, only the right side is a proxy object, as you mentioned. Hope that makes sense, thanks for the comment :-)

Comment: I see. now  I do not expect them to be the same class, but what you said in that comment makes sense.  Thank you.